# what's the Lua syntax used in Wireshak Tvb

Tags: lua, wireshark

In Wireshark Lua Dissectors page:
https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Dissectors

It said:
A TvbRange represents a usable range of a Tvb and is used to extract data from the Tvb that generated it.
TvbRanges are created by calling a Tvb (e.g. 'tvb(offset,length)'). If the TvbRange span is outside the Tvb's range the creation will cause a runtime error.

```
-- trivial protocol example
-- declare our protocol
trivial_proto = Proto("trivial","Trivial Protocol")
-- create a function to dissect it
function trivial_proto.dissector(buffer,pinfo,tree)
    pinfo.cols.protocol = "TRIVIAL"
    local subtree = tree:add(trivial_proto,buffer(),"Trivial Protocol Data")
    subtree:add(buffer(0,2),"The first two bytes: " .. buffer(0,2):uint())
    subtree = subtree:add(buffer(2,2),"The next two bytes")
    subtree:add(buffer(2,1),"The 3rd byte: " .. buffer(2,1):uint())
    subtree:add(buffer(3,1),"The 4th byte: " .. buffer(3,1):uint())
end
-- load the udp.port table
udp_table = DissectorTable.get("udp.port")
-- register our protocol to handle udp port 7777
udp_table:add(7777,trivial_proto)
```

The expresion "buffer(2,1)" create a TvbRanges from a Tvb object，what's the syntax in lua?
Here ,we pass two parameter to a object, not a function, what's mean, how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to call something that's not a function, Lua looks for a `__call` metamethod on it, and calls that instead if it exists. For this particular object, https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Tvb.html#lua_fn_tvb___call__ says it's equivalent to calling the `:range()` method on it, e.g., you could replace `buffer(2,2)` with `buffer:range(2,2)`.

Comment: Thanks very much. This problem bothered me  for some time. My lua knowledge mainly from "Programming in Lua" which don't mention __call metamethod. Now I find it in "Lua 5.3 Reference Manual".